# How to Get Radio Button Name and Id by its Tag Name when It is Checked?

Tags: javascript

my code is here where i am counting the all radio button and checked radio button,

```
var selection=new Array(); 
 var allR = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var a=0;
  var b=0;
    for(var i=0; i<allR.length; i++){ 
        if(allR[i].type=='radio') { b++; }      
        if(allR[i].type=='radio' && allR[i].checked) { a++; } 
    }
```

how to get radio button name and its id by its Tag name ???

hopes for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

So when you have your collection of elements stored in allR, you can get ids and names by getAttribute method, because ids and names are just usual attributes

```
element.getAttribute('id') element.getAttribute('name')
```

Answer (score 0):

use it like this

```
<script>
var rad = document.getElementbyId('rad_id').value;
</script>
<input type="radio" id="rad_id" value="my value">
```

its result will be

```
`my value`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put

```
alert(allR[i].getAttribute('id') + ', ' + allR[i].getAttribute('name'));
```

inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the name: `allR[i].name`. You can get the ID in a similar manner: `allR[i].id`.